# How to create image manager with multiple image storage in opencart

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, opencart

I am currently working on Open Cart Eshop. In that open cart frontend, I just want to show 
file manager like product form in admin.In admin panel, product image  can be added and removed by using javascript.Further, file manager can be used to upload files for product.
Just like that, front end can be used to show file manager and upload concept.  Here i am using this code to show image concept.

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
var image_row = <?php echo $image_row; ?>;

function addImage() {

    html  = '<tbody id="image-row">';
    html += '  <tr>';
    html += '<td class="left"><div class="image"><img src="image/no_image.jpg" alt="" id="thumb" /></td>';
html += '  </tr>';
    html += '</tbody>';

    $('#images tfoot').before(html);

    image_row++;
}
//--></script>
```

further, i can`t proceed to other work for file manager..I can`t show it file manager in front end..

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
function image_upload(field,thumb) {
    alert(thumb);
    alert(field);

    $('#dialog').remove();

    $('#content').prepend('<div id="dialog" style="padding: 3px 0px 0px 0px;"><iframe src="index.php?route=common/filemanager&field=' + encodeURIComponent(field) + '" style="padding:0; margin: 0; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%;" frameborder="no" scrolling="auto"></iframe></div>');

$('#dialog').dialog({
        title: '<?php echo $text_image_manager; ?>',
        close: function (event, ui) {
            if ($('#' + field).attr('value')) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'index.php?route=common/filemanager/image&token=<?php echo $token; ?>&image=' + encodeURIComponent($('#' + field).attr('value')),
                    dataType: 'text',
                    success: function(text) {
                        $('#' + thumb).replaceWith('<img src="' + text + '" alt="" id="' + thumb + '" />');
                    }
                });
            }
        },  
        bgiframe: false,
        width: 800,
        height: 400,
        resizable: false,
        modal: false
    });
}
//--></script>
```

This script doesn`t working for image manager in frontend..I am struggling this concept nearly one week.Here this is example URL..for me..[This is example url not my site.](http://www.netbaski.com/printing/fotograf-baskisi/4359/editor).I just want to show image manager like this above url.How can i solve it...Please guide me...I am struggling for one week..

(sorry for bad English)

Comment: So just to be sure, You want to let the users/visitors to upload images to the products on product's detail page?

Comment: Ya...I think got my idea,My needs, users can upload their product image and move into cart page then payment, just like a normal product,can you provide some idea for this?

Comment: What would You need this image for? If it is like *I want to print this image on this paper* (while the paper is the product), then You could use **Product options** and create new option of type **File** (file upload) and make it mandatory. Then if user wants to buy the product (paper, printing service, etc) he would have to upload the image first. I guess this is what You are looking for...

Comment: Thank u @shadyyx....

Actually we are working with multiple file upload for a single product in open cart.  When user come and click a product, they have been forward to the select the product size and then it will be directed to the next page, there is option to upload multiple files with the quantity option for each file.  Because this for Photo Album, so users can upload upto 500 images for make an order.  So for this, i have to do the multiple images upload for under photo album product.  This need to be available in backend.  Do you understand? and help me in this file upload concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the purpose of image uploading prior to buying of product it is the easiest to use the **Product options**. I will describe the steps You need to take to create the option and then set it to desired product:

1. In administration, go to `Catalog` -> `Options`, then click on `Insert`.
2. In the form set

   - the option's name, e.g. *Image to print*
   - the type to ***File***
   - the sorting order to the desired number, e.g. *1*.
3. Hit `Save`.
4. Now that we have created the option, go to `Catalog` -> `Products` and click on `Edit` for the product You wish to add the option to.
5. Select the tab `Option` and on the left side start typing "Image" (without quotes) into the input with the green *plus* button to the right.
6. The autocomplete feature should immediately hint the full option name *Image to print* - click on it and click on that green *plus* button - the option will be added to the product.
7. Now only select whether the *Image to print* will be required or not and click on `Save`.
8. You are done.

I'd suggest making the file upload mandatory (required) if it is a condition for buying the product.

Comment: Thank U @shadyyx..I will more helpful for me...thank for guide me..
Here I just follow to create this like...http://www.netbaski.com/printing/fotograf-baskisi/4359/editor..is it possible?

Comment: It is possible, but You would have to find and download that kind of filemanager and replace the one OpenCart uses on frontend with it. It could be tricky but not impossible.

Comment: Thank U @shadyyx.....I just googling for file manager,doesnt have any more..Let me update it in anywhere..else  I desired to create default file manager in front end...In image manager can be editable or not..Let me know for it...

Comment: I am not sure that I understand this: `In image manager can be editable or not..`. Could You please rephrase the *question*?

Comment: sorry for this..@shadyyx...In that file manager, will be modified for my convenience just like that http://www.netbaski.com/printing/fotograf-baskisi/4359/editor...I need to create session for directory.When particular user can create their own directory in left side means It will shown that user alone.I just need to be editable for this file manager,Is there any way to do this..directory and image will be depends upon users.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a customer to use image manager in the front end you will have to copy it to the catalog folder preferably in the same directory tree order after the controller folder as the files are in the admin section. Ex route = common/filemanager/image in the front end is looking for store/catalog/common/filemanage.php and /image as the method or function inside this file. So you have to copy files to the store side that will be needed, maybe change some routes, build a routine to decide who can use to tool and to what extent the tool can be used.
Hope this helps.
I happen to be working on a similar project.